# SQL can't nullif

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a stored procedure cannot value 0 if textbox empty in UnitLimitValue. So what query in my stored procedure give value 0 in UnitLimitValue?

```
values (@UnitID, @UnitDescription, NULLIF(@UnitLimitValue, '0')
```

Comment: I think you need `ISNULL`

Comment: why not tell your parameter to value to 0 if the textbox is empty application side instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
values (@UnitID,@UnitDescription,
case when @UnitLimitValue='' then 0 else @UnitLimitValue end)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
values (@UnitID, @UnitDescription,NULLIF(TRY_PARSE(@UnitLimitValue AS decimal), '0')
```

this can solve if any conversion problems exist